# Use jQuery Plugins in Magento 2 blocks

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I'm trying to use jQuery camera inside a page block, but I'm doing something wrong.

I added the camera.min.js into my custom theme folder
Theme_folder/Magento_Theme/web/js/camera.min.js

Here's my requirejs-config.js in Theme_folder/Magento_Theme/web/js/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'camera': './js/camera.min'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        'camera': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jQuery.camera'
        }
    }
};
```

And here's the js in the block:

```
require(['jquery', 'camera'], function(jQuery) {
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#camera_wrap').camera({
            alignmen: 'topCenter',
            height: '36.341%',
            minHeight: '134px',
            loader : false,
            pagination: false,
            fx: 'simpleFade',
            navigationHover:false,
            thumbnails: false,
            playPause: false
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirejs-config.js file is in the wrong directory. It should go directly in your theme directory. If you want to make sure your requirejs-config file is being read properly, you can open the sources tab in your chrome inspector, navigate to `pub/static/_requirejs/{area}/{vendor}/{theme}/{locale}/requirejs-config.js`. You will see a merged document of all the requirejs-config.js files in magento including yours. If you do a search for "camera" you should see your mapping if everything worked properly.

You should change your js to this

```
require(['jquery', 'camera'], function(jQuery) {
    return function(){
        jQuery('#camera_wrap').camera({
            alignmen: 'topCenter',
            height: '36.341%',
            minHeight: '134px',
            loader : false,
            pagination: false,
            fx: 'simpleFade',
            navigationHover:false,
            thumbnails: false,
            playPause: false
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Magento 2 documentation is very confusing regarding where each file should be. I moved the requirejs-config.js and now it's loading, but I got this error: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Thank you for letting us know. Can you point us to any topic in particular that confused you? Where should we add more detail?